# When enumerating a MatchCollection, why does var result in Object type rather than Match type?

Tags: c#, regex

I noticed something that seems odd in the following code:

```
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(myString, myPattern);
foreach(var match in mc)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Captures[0]); // <-- this line is invalid, unless I replace 'var' above with 'Match'
```

The variable `match` is of type `Object` rather than `Match`. I am used to enumerating collections using `var` with no issues like this. Why is `MatchCollection` different?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`MatchCollection` was written before .NET 2, so it just implements `IEnumerable` rather than `IEnumerable<T>`. However, you can use `Cast` to fix this very easily:

```
foreach(var match in mc.Cast<Match>())
```

If you give the variable an explicit type, like this:

```
foreach(Match match in mc)
```

... then the C# compiler inserts a cast on each item for you automatically. This was required in C# 1 to avoid having casts all over your code.

(Logically even with `var` there's a conversion involved - but it's always from one type to the same type, so nothing actually needs to be emitted.) See section 8.8.4 of the C# 4 spec for more details.

Comment: Makes you wonder why when releasing .NET > v2 they did not do the simple step of implementing `IEnumerable<Match>` as they did with other collection types

Comment: @Jamiec: Which other collection types did they actually *update* as opposed to implementing in new classes? There can be subtle problems involved in starting to implement an interface later. Note that the same thing occurs elsewhere, e.g. DataTable.

Comment: Thanks @Jon, surprised I have not run into this before. Would be interested to know of the subtle problems you refer to some time, but perhaps this is not the place...

Comment: @Jon - Assumption is the mother of all *muck* up. Having gone back and looked at the ones i'd *assumed* were updated made me discover they either weren't (eg, DataTable) or didn't exist prior to 2.0

Comment: @Jon: SO at its best. Thanks Jon. That was exactly my problem, exactly my question and exactly the answer I needed. But I do wonder why <T> has not been implemented, just for consistency.

Comment: @david.pfx: I suspect it would be very hard to do so without it being a breaking change or introducing confusion. It would certainly be nice though, I agree.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'm sure you're right. I've been using C# since the PDC in 2000, and if we knew then what we know now...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach(Match match in mc)
```

Since [`MatchCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.aspx) does not implement `IEnumerable<T>` the enumerator in the `foreach` will receive an `object` for each `Match` in the sequence.  It is your job to cast the object to the right type.

So when you use `var` in the foreach loop you are *implicitly* typing `match` to `object` since that is what is being yielded by the enumerator.  By *explicitly* typing `match` to `Match` you are instructing the compiler to cast each match to the right type on your behalf.

Comment: OP does mention (in code comment) `Match match` fixes it but was wondering why `var` does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Using var is inappropriate in that context.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx

"However, the use of var does have at least the potential to make your code more difficult to understand for other developers. For that reason, the C# documentation generally uses **var only when it is required.**"

Comment: This is not a question of readability. To me, when enumerating a `MatchCollection`, it seemed a safe assumption (and pretty readable too) that it would yield a `Match`. I appreciate the answer, but saying something is inappropriate is not that informative when this is a "why" question.